# Insert data from files into SQLite database

Tags: python, bash, sqlite

I have an SQLite database on this form:

```
Table1

Column1 | Column 2 | Column 3 | Column 4
```

I want to populate this database with data stored in some hundred .out files in this form, where every file has millions of rows:

```
value1;value2;value3;value4;
2value1;2value2;2value3;2value4;
... etc
```

Is there a fast way to populate the database with these data? One way would be to read in the data line for line in python and insert, however there probably should be a faster way to just input the whole file?

Bash, SQLite, Python preferrably

Comment: Take a look at http://pythonhosted.org/querycsv/ where the csv is translated into sqlite to provide sql interface.

Comment: https://sqlite.org/cvstrac/wiki?p=ImportingFiles

Answer (score 5, accepted):

SQLite has a [`.import`](https://www.sqlite.org/cli.html) command.

> `.import FILE TABLE`     Import data from FILE into TABLE

You can use it like this (shell).

```
for f in *.out
do
    sqlite3 -separator ';' my.db ".import $f Table1"
done
```

Comment: Is it a problem that every line ends with a ; ? I get "expected 7 columns but found 8 - extras ignored". Do you think this slows down the process in any way?

Comment: I don't know. You could strip the trailing `;` first and try.